# Git: show full log (or diff) of commits which modified a given file

Tags: git, filter, git-diff, git-log

If I do:

```
git log --stat -p -- my/file
```

I get the list of every commit which modified `my/file`, but it only displays the file list and diff (respectively `--stat` and `-p`) regarding `my/file`, thus hiding the full commit changelog.

How can I display the full log (modified files and full diff) of this list of commits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for:

```
--full-diff
           Without this flag, "git log -p <path>..." shows commits that touch
           the specified paths, and diffs about the same specified paths. With
           this, the full diff is shown for commits that touch the specified
           paths; this means that "<path>..." limits only commits, and doesn't
           limit diff for those commits.
```

?